# Indefinite Integral of $\dfrac {x^{p-1}}{x^{2m} - a^{2m}}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am looking at a bunch of related integrals found in Spiegel's "Mathematical Handbook of Formulas and Tables", (Schaum, 1968), item $14.336$.

It's a complicated and messy old beast:

For $m \in \mathbb Z$ such that $m \ge 1$:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac {x^{p-1} \, \mathrm d x}{x^{2m} - a^{2m}} = \frac 1 {2 m a^{2 m - p}} \sum_{k=1}^m \cos \frac {k p \pi} m \ln \left({x^2 - 2 a x \cos \frac {k \pi} m + a^2}\right)$

$\displaystyle - \frac 1 {m a^{2 m - p}} \sum_{k=1}^m \sin \frac {k p \pi} m \arctan \left({\frac {x - a \cos \frac {k \pi} m}{a \sin \frac {k \pi} m}}\right)$

$\displaystyle + \frac 1 {2 m a^{2 m - p}} (\ln (x - a) + (-1)^p \ln (x + a)) + C$

for all $0 < p \le 2 m$.

(Note that he glosses over the sign of $x$, presenting the expression for positive $x$ only -- I will explore the negative $x$ case later.)

I thought of $2$ different approaches:

1. Factorise the denominator using the standard result:

$\displaystyle x^{2 n} - y^{2 n} = (x - y) (x + y) \prod_{k \mathop = 1}^{n - 1} \left({x^2 - 2 x y \cos \dfrac {k \pi} n + y^2}\right)$

and then explore the possibility of doing a partial fraction expansion. However, this did not work out so well, as I was then unable to see how to simplify the expression on the top of the resulting terms in all but the $x - a$ and $x + a$ denominators, so I didn't proceed further with that.

2. Prove it by induction on $m$, which first concerns establishing the base case:

$\displaystyle \int \frac {\mathrm d x} {x^2 - a^2} = \frac 1 {2 a} \ln \left({\dfrac {x - a} {x + a}}\right) + C$ (that is: $m = 1$, $p = 1$)

$\displaystyle \int \frac {x \, \mathrm d x} {x^2 - a^2} = \ln \left({x^2 - a^2}\right) + C$ (that is: $m = 1$, $p = 2$)

But when I put $m = 1$ into the above expression, I get:

$\dfrac 1 {2 a^{2 - p} } ( (-1)^p \ln (x^2 + 2 a x + a^2) ) + \dfrac 1 {2 a^{2 - p} } (\ln (x - a) + (-1)^p \ln (x + a) )$

But that pesky term on the left, in $(-1)^p \ln (x^2 + 2 a x + a^2)$ is clearly incorrect.

This arises from the $\cos \dfrac {k p \pi} m \ln \left({x^2 - 2 a x \cos \dfrac {k \pi} m + a^2}\right)$ expression in the given solution.

But for integer $p$ and $m = 1$, that $\cos \dfrac {k p \pi} m$ term, which I would hope to vanish, defiantly remains in place.

It doesn't help much changing it to $\cos \dfrac {k p \pi} {2 m}$, because this time it does not vanish for $p = 2$.

So either Spiegel has reported this result wrong, or I'm misunderstanding something.

Should that cosine in fact be a sine? Then it would vanish away like I want it to.

For $m = 2$ and $p = 1$ you get this:

$\dfrac 1 {4 a^3} \ln \left( {\dfrac {x - a} {x + a} }\right) - \dfrac 1 {2 a^3} \arctan \dfrac x a$

which is consistent with the result quoted. I have gone a little further, trying $p = 2, 3, 4$, but now it is looking as though the cosine term is completely erroneous and perhaps should not be there at all, because any contribution it makes is consistently absent.

I have gone no further with higher $m$ values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sane way to do this is using complex functions.  The integrand is a rational function with simple poles at $x = \omega_k a$ where $\omega_k =e^{\pi i k /m} $, $k = 0,1,\ldots, 2m-1$ are the  $2m$'th roots of unity:

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^{p-1}}{x^{2m} - a^{2m}} = \frac{x^{p-1}}{\prod_{k=0}^{2m-1} (x - \omega_k a)}$$

Its residue at $x=\omega_k$, is then $$\text{res}(f, \omega_k a) = \frac{(\omega_k a)^{p - 2m}}{2m}$$
so that
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} \frac{(\omega_k a)^{p-2m}}{2m (x - \omega_k a)} $$
which has an indefinite integral
$$ F(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} \frac{(\omega_k a)^{p-2m}}{2m} \log (x - \omega_k a) $$
For positive real $x$ and $a$ we can write
$$\log(x - \omega_k a) = \frac{1}{2} \log(x^2 - 2a \cos(2\pi k /m) x + a^2) - i \arctan \left(\frac{a \sin(2 \pi k/m)}{x - a \cos(2\pi k /m)}\right)$$
$$ (\omega_k a)^{p-2m} = a^{p-2m} \left(\cos(p k \pi/m) + i \sin(p k \pi/m)\right)$$
and the formula follows.

Comment: Thank you for this. I briefly examined the technique from which one derives the factorisation formula in the first place, which exploits the properties of the conjugate nature of the complex roots, but didn't take that extra step of deciding to perform the entire integration in the complex domain in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in the formula

\begin{align}
I(m,p) =\int \dfrac {x^{p-1} \, \mathrm d x}{x^{2m} - a^{2m}}
& = \frac 1 {2 m a^{2 m - p}} \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \cos \frac {k p \pi} m \ln \left({x^2 - 2 a x \cos \frac {k \pi} m + a^2}\right)\\
 & \>\>\>\>\>- \frac 1 {m a^{2 m - p}} \sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\sin \frac {k p \pi} m \arctan \left({\frac {x - a \cos \frac {k \pi} m}{a \sin \frac {k \pi} m}}\right)\\
 & \>\>\>\>\>+ \frac 1 {2 m a^{2 m - p}} (\ln (x - a) + (-1)^p \ln (x + a))
\end{align}
where the summation should run from $1$ to $m-1$, instead of $m$. Then, the followings check out
$$I(1,1)=\int \frac {\mathrm d x} {x^2 - a^2} = \frac 1 {2 a} \ln \left({\dfrac {x - a} {x + a}}\right)$$

$$I(1,2)=\int \frac {x \, \mathrm d x} {x^2 - a^2} = \ln \left({x^2 - a^2}\right)$$

$$I(2,1)=\int \frac {\, \mathrm d x} {x^4 - a^4}
= \dfrac 1 {4 a^3} \ln \left( {\dfrac {x - a} {x + a} }\right) - \dfrac 1 {2 a^3} \arctan \dfrac x a$$

Comment: Thank you, I see it now. The mistake is completely mine.